# React Native Swipe Gestures not working in android

Tags: react-native, swipe-gesture

I'am facing a problem with swipe gestures not responding in android as I'am using react-native swipe gestures. It works fine in IOS. Below is the source code for the same.

```
constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);
  this.swipeConfig = Object.assign(swipeConfig, props.config);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  this.swipeConfig = Object.assign(swipeConfig, props.config);
}

componentWillMount() {
  const responderEnd = this._handlePanResponderEnd.bind(this);
  const shouldSetResponder = this._handleShouldSetPanResponder.bind(this);
  this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({ //stop JS beautify collapse
  onStartShouldSetPanResponder: shouldSetResponder,
  onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: shouldSetResponder,
  onPanResponderRelease: responderEnd,
  onPanResponderTerminate: responderEnd
});
}

_handleShouldSetPanResponder(evt, gestureState) {
  return evt.nativeEvent.touches.length === 1 && 
  !this._gestureIsClick(gestureState);
}

_gestureIsClick(gestureState) {
  return Math.abs(gestureState.dx) < 5  && Math.abs(gestureState.dy) < 5;
 }

_handlePanResponderEnd(evt, gestureState) {
  const swipeDirection = this._getSwipeDirection(gestureState);
  this._triggerSwipeHandlers(swipeDirection, gestureState);
 }

_triggerSwipeHandlers(swipeDirection, gestureState) {
  const {onSwipe, onSwipeUp, onSwipeDown, onSwipeLeft, onSwipeRight} = 
  this.props;
  const {SWIPE_LEFT, SWIPE_RIGHT, SWIPE_UP, SWIPE_DOWN} = swipeDirections;
  onSwipe && onSwipe(swipeDirection, gestureState);
  switch (swipeDirection) {
    case SWIPE_LEFT:
      onSwipeLeft && onSwipeLeft(gestureState);
      break;
    case SWIPE_RIGHT:
      onSwipeRight && onSwipeRight(gestureState);
      break;
    case SWIPE_UP:
      onSwipeUp && onSwipeUp(gestureState);
      break;
    case SWIPE_DOWN:
      onSwipeDown && onSwipeDown(gestureState);
      break;
    }
   }

  _getSwipeDirection(gestureState) {
    const {SWIPE_LEFT, SWIPE_RIGHT, SWIPE_UP, SWIPE_DOWN} = swipeDirections;
    const {dx, dy} = gestureState;
    if (this._isValidHorizontalSwipe(gestureState)) {
      return (dx > 0)
      ? SWIPE_RIGHT
      : SWIPE_LEFT;
    } else if (this._isValidVerticalSwipe(gestureState)) {
      return (dy > 0)
      ? SWIPE_DOWN
      : SWIPE_UP;
    }
    return null;
  }

  _isValidHorizontalSwipe(gestureState) {
    const {vx, dy} = gestureState;
    const {velocityThreshold, directionalOffsetThreshold} = 
    this.swipeConfig;
    return isValidSwipe(vx, velocityThreshold, dy, 
    directionalOffsetThreshold);
  }

  _isValidVerticalSwipe(gestureState) {
    const {vy, dx} = gestureState;
    const {velocityThreshold, directionalOffsetThreshold} = 
    this.swipeConfig;
    return isValidSwipe(vy, velocityThreshold, dx, 
    directionalOffsetThreshold);
  }

  render() {
    return (<View {...this.props} {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}/>);
  }
};
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?